# Iget syntax error. where my select query is wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

I try to search in a followup table with date and wrote for that 3 input, today, yesterday and of x date to y date. I wrote for this search these codes but I get syntax error.

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `call_date_sh`DESC) > 0 THEN 1 END DESC, CASE WHEN (...' at line 3 in search_result.php:135

Where am I wrong?

```
$search_q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `followup` $fields_in_query ORDER BY
        
        CASE WHEN (
            SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(`call_date_sh`,'%Y-%m-%d') > CURDATE() AND  DATE_FORMAT(`call_date_sh`,'%Y-%m-%d') != CURDATE() ORDER BY `call_date_sh` DESC LIMIT 0, 1
            ) > 0 THEN 1 END DESC,
        
        CASE WHEN (
            SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(`call_date_sh`,'%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() ORDER BY `call_date_sh` DESC LIMIT 0, 1
            ) > 0  THEN 1 END DESC,
        
        CASE WHEN (
            SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`call_date_sh`,'%Y-%m-%d') < CURDATE() ORDER BY `call_date_sh` DESC LIMIT 0, 1
            ) > 0 THEN 2 END DESC
            
        
         limit $start, $count");
```

my table is:

```
id    call_date_sh           date_t        f_name
1     2021-11-10 18:10:25    1401-02-25    Sorena
2     2022-05-13 11:27:45    1401-06-20    Atoosa
3     2021-12-05 15:12:05    1401-01-28    Radman
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: error is:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `call_date_sh` DESC) &gt; 0 THEN 1 END DESC, CASE WHEN (...' at line 3 in E:\xampp\htdocs\paziresh-final -xx\exam\followup\search_result.php:135

Comment: Where is your CASE condition?
you write CASE "SOME CONDITION" then do whatever it's to do 
another CASE "ANOTHER CONDITION"

Comment: First, the SQL in your error message doesn't appear in your question anywhere. Second, what's the point of using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` for an un-grouped `COUNT` query?

Comment: Not sure what's in the `$fields_in_query` variable, but I do not see a `WHERE` clause?